# href links only open on "right click in new tab"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hyperlink, href

I'm having trouble with some script interfering with my basic href links and not allowing them to open on left click.

My url is http://www.mayabdesign.com, and on each specific project page (like http://www.mayabdesign.com/#cbp=ajax/sculptjax.html) the "view the site" button does nothing unless you right click and open in a new tab. I know the problem, but can't seem to figure out the solution.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: can you provide a fiddle???

Answer (score 1):

Add click function to `Dom Ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function( event ) {
          if ( $(this).attr("href").match("#") ) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')
          scrollToAnchor( href );
    });
});
```

**[CHECK DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/25zSc/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think the  click events are blocked somewhere with event.preventDefault()

Answer (score -1):

This is the relevent code that is preventing the link from returning. Since the href value does in fact math `#` its default action is prevented

```
$("a").click(function( event ) {
      if ( $(this).attr("href").match("#") ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var href = $(this).attr('href').replace('#', '')
      scrollToAnchor( href );
});
```

Comment: I removed that bit of script and the links still didn't work. I'm (clearly) not very knowledgable in the script side of things when it comes to creating a website. I really want to thank you guys for taking the time to try to help me.

Comment: Try cleaning your cache